# Characterisation of reflexive modules for general rings

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

A module $M$ over a general ring A is called reflexive in case the canonical evaluation map $e_M: M \rightarrow M^{**}$ is an isomorphism, when $(-)^{*}:=Hom_A(-,A)$. Is $M$ reflexive iff $M \cong M^{**}$ for some isomorphism?
I am interested in counterexamples or proofs for finitely generated or finitely presented $M$. See [Are there non-reflexive modules isomorphic to their bi-dual?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76000/are-there-non-reflexive-modules-isomorphic-to-their-bi-dual) for a counter example for infinitely generated $M$.
For a positive answer in special cases see [Characterisation of reflexive modules](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288878/characterisation-of-reflexive-modules) .

Comment: I would expect that this is something which should have been thought about in the literature already so maybe there is an article about such things?