# Non-reflexive Banach space s.t. X,X*,X**,... are separable

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Is there an infinite-dimensional Banach space $X$, which is not reflexive, such that all the spaces $X,X^{\ast},X^{\ast\ast}, X^{\ast\ast\ast},\dots$ are separable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the James space is an example.  It is isomorphic to its double dual (but not by the canonical embedding).

Comment: Yes, James space has $X^{**}/X$ of dimension $1$.  For example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James%27_space Also http://mathoverflow.net/a/43987/454

Comment: Also, for each n James has constructed a space X whose nth dual is the first non-separable space.