# $C$ is **weakly compact** or **weakly locally compact**?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, compactness

Let $X$ be a separable Banach space such that $X$ and its dual $X^*$ have Radon-Nikodym property. Let $C$ be a convex, closed and bounded subset of $X$.

Can we say that $C$ is **weakly compact** or **weakly locally compact**?

An idea please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closed unit ball of a Banach space $X$ is weakly compact if and only if it is reflexive. So if $X$ is a non-reflexive space such that $X$ and its dual have RNP, take $C$ to be the unit ball to see that the answer to your first question is negative.

For instance, takes $X$ to be the classical James space; its dual is separable, hence has RNP; its bidual is also separable, hence has RNP; and $X$ is a closed subspace of $X^{**}$ hence also has RNP.

I suspect that the same counterexample also works for "locally weakly compact" but I have not checked the details.

Comment: Perhaps the reason for a conjecture like the OP is that the James space is relatively unknonwn.  See https://mathoverflow.net/a/43987/454

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Indeed. I must confess that I spent quite a while scratching my head and thinking of "classical" spaces before eventually hittting on the idea "when can the bidual be separable without the space being reflexive"

Comment: If $C$ is closed and convex, it's weakly closed; so weak compactness and weak local compactness are the same.

Comment: @DirkWerner Thanks: I suspected as much but was too tired when I wrote the original example to check that I wasn't making a silly oversight